# How to enable wifi hardware switch in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wifi-hardware-switch

**i'm running ubuntu 16.04**

Recently on the network manager a message was shown like `Wifi hardware switch disabled` and i tried to restart network-manager by `sudo service network-manager restart` when it restarted wifi is working but now the icon disappeared from system tray.

i have tried few commands wich is in the other post but it didn't fixed my issue

```
rfkill unblock all
rfkill list

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
25: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of: `rfkill list all`

Comment: On a DELL XPS 13 9343 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I ran into the message 'Wi-Fi disabled by hardware switch'. The message was noted when I was unable to enable Wi-Fi for no particular reason that I am aware. The problem disappeared after invoking 'Shutdown' and 'Restart'. I suspect it's some incompatibility in the firmware but don't have any specific information about that.